# Does this program end in an infinite loop? How can I tell?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I run the program and all I see is white space below Netbeans.

At first I thought it did not run then I ran four of the programs by accident and Netbeans crashed. So my first question: is it an infinite loop, and if so why?

From what I can see it is `int = 0`, `0` is `>=0` So it should run  as `0 + 0`... wait if `int number` and `int sum` are both zero then does that mean the program can't proceed because it is stuck with looping zeros? But why wouldn't it show the output of 0 many times instead of being blank?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int number = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    while (number >= 0 || number <= 10) {
        sum += number;
        number += 3;
        System.out.print(" Sum is " + sum);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Although the main question has been answered, I do want to point out why it wasn't printing anything during the loop. Java doesn't print anything to the console until it hits the end of a line, either from a System.out.println() or an "\n" included in a printed string. Because you're using print, but not using a carriage return, you won't see any output until the program exits. I hope that helps with future debugging.

Comment: @Dogmatixed nice explaination

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think through the logic yourself. When will the number ever not be greater than or equal to 0?  You know you have an or operator (`||`), and you know that it will be true if either statement on the right or left are true.  Maybe you want to use a different operator there?

Again think through the logic as it won't lie to you. In fact you should walk through your code with a pencil and paper starting with 0, and seeing what happens on paper as this will show you your error.

Comment: i completely didn't even look at the or statement.. i kept over passing it, damn i feel dumb.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's an infinite loop, you probably meant:

```
while (number >= 0 && number <= 10)
```

Otherwise, the number will always be greater than or equal zero, and will always loop again.

EDIT:

The `number >= 0` isn't even necessary. It will work with just:

```
while (number <= 10)
```

Comment: Yeah i just didn't even think about the or statement ... feel kind of dumb now but thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will be an infinite loop
|| means or

```
while (a || b) {
  //do something
}
```

you only need to satisfy ANY ONE CONDITION (be it a, or b, or both) for the while loop to execute.

As for why a bunch of whitespaces instead of a bunch of zeros, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

You step through it in the debugger!!

It's worth learning how to use the debugger especially if you're not got at spotting bugs manually yet.